# How to understand EG White's (SDA) comment on Revelation 14?

Tags: seventh-day-adventists, matthew, luke, doctrine, mark

> (Exodus 31:13-17) What is God's Sign?-The sign of obedience is the observance of the Sabbath of the fourth commandment.If men keep the fourth commandment,they will keep all the rest(Letter 31,1898)(7BC 981.5)

The above comment is from E G White commenting on Revelation 14.She articulates that those who observe the fourth commandment(Sabbath) will also keep the rest

But in many instances the pharisaic order who were keen observers of the Sabbath were lambasted for observing the Sabbath while neglecting the other laws.

Luke 6:1-2 NASB

> Now it happened that [a]Jesus was passing through some grainfields on a Sabbath, and His disciples were picking the heads of grain, rubbing them in their hands, and eating them. 2 **But some of the Pharisees said, “Why are you doing what is not lawful on the Sabbath?”**

Luke 6:6 NASB

> On another Sabbath He entered the synagogue and taught; and a man was there [c]whose right hand was withered. 7 **Now the scribes and the Pharisees were watching Him [d]closely to see if He healed on the Sabbath, so that they might find a reason to accuse Him**.

Even when the greatest commandments are mentioned the Sabbath is conspicuous by its absence from the list

Matthew 22:36-40 NASB

> 36 “Teacher, which is the great commandment in the Law?” 37 And He said to him, “‘You shall love the Lord your God with all your heart, and with all your soul, and with all your mind.’ 38 This is the great and [u]foremost commandment. 39 The second is like it, ‘You shall love your neighbor as yourself.’ 40 Upon these two commandments [v]hang the whole Law and the Prophets.”

Mark 10:19 NASB

> You know the commandments: ‘Do not murder, Do not commit adultery, Do not steal, Do not give false testimony, Do not defraud, Honor your father and mother.’”

How then can one understand the assertion that those who keep the fourth commandment will also observe the other laws

How can one understand this assertion?

Comment: Just for clarity - are you asking how Ellen White would defend her beliefs on the importance of the sabbath in relation to Jesus’s actions that seemingly “violated” the Sabbath?

Comment: Jesus did not lambast the pharasees for keeping the Sabbath...he lambasted them for the way they kept it! Big difference. Jesus actions did not violate the Sabbath, he was simply reminding what the purpose of the Sabbath was...whilst it was always a special day of worship, it was not meant to be a burden. The pharasees had turned it into a day of burden by adding all sorts of largely self serving restrictions.

Comment: The statement "If men keep the fourth commandment, they would keep all the rest" actually means "If men keep the fourth commandment as they should, they would keep all the rest". The Pharisees did not keep the Sabbath as it should be kept. Jesus kept the Sabbath as it should be kept. So you see Jesus keeping all 10 commandments while the Pharisees claiming to keep the commandments killed the Innocent One (Jesus) on the cross (6th commandment). They were covetous (10th commandment) of Jesus and arranged for false witnesses (9th commandment) to kill Him and so on...